# Jquery Copy HTML text into email browser

Tags: jquery, asp.net, email

So I have the following problem.

At the moment I am outputting HTML text from a CMS, this HTML is a customized email template. Which is a simple as

```
<p>Hi</P>
<p>THis is your URL : http://www.yoursite.com?id=15151</p>
<p>Thanks</p>
<p>Company X</p>
```

And we are outputting this to the screen.

What I am looking for is a sort jquery button which is called "Copy" and it copies the text above and they can paste in email later and keeps formatting.

Comment: Look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: Can you define "paste in email"? Is this email HTML based, rich-text based, plain text?  And are you talking about placing the "formatted text" into the clipboard?

Answer (score 0):

(For cross-browser copy-to-clipboard, this is possibly a duplicate question: [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript))

Using this library, https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard, (mentioned in the post above), you'd want to wrap your to-be-copied source text in something with an ID, like so:

```
<div class="emailText">
    <p>Hi</P>
    <p>THis is your URL : http://www.yoursite.com?id=15151</p>
    <p>Thanks</p>
    <p>Company X</p>
</div>
```

Then, in the Javascript call that sets the text for the library, you'd do something like:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
  clip.setText( $(".emailText").html() );
  clip.glue( 'd_clip_button' );
</script>
```